# How to hide Windows Media Player controls with code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I add the Windows Media Player element to my Visual Studio C# project, it doesn't seem to work right. When you open the properties window for the element and select "hidden" for the control viability, it should hide the controls completely when the program is running. For me, when I hit the start button to run the test program, the controls are still at the bottom. When I see tutorials on how to use the WMP element the controls are hidden when the test project is running. I'm not sure what's happening.

Is there a way for me to hide the controls using code? Because no matter what I try to do, the controls are still shown when in the test application and in the published version. If there is another solution to this problem for Visual Studio 2022, please let me know.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You will have to share some screen shots for others to understand better what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

UiMode: String player interface mode in WindowsMediaPlayer controls can be divided into Full, Mini, None, And Invisible.

Using Visual Studio 2022, you can set uiMode to none in the code for this problem.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
    }
```

The effect of the code rendering：
[image]